# Help needed with rails facebook connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authlogic, fbconnect, facebooker

I need to connect facebook with rails. I have googled for the examples and tutotrials but nothing much was helpful. I have tried both the facebooker and authlogic but could not succeed in connecting rails application with facebook. If anyone could tell me about a good plugin for that it would be couteous.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/), it's pretty good.

Comment: The Koala gem is good. I use the javascript api for authentication and use https://github.com/james2m/authlogic_facebook_shim to login with authlogic.

Comment: For authentication I hear that OmniAuth (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) is supposed to be pretty good as well